# What is the location of Ubuntu website files on Windows 10?

Tags: shell, windows-10

I'm trying the access the files (website files) without bash but I can't find them. This is in regards to the Ubuntu that comes with Windows 10.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by website files

Comment: I mean the /var/www/html directory.

Comment: What web service are you trying to run that can't be ran by windows?

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu on windows 10 and I want to access the directory without using bash.

Comment: This existing answer appears correct.  http://askubuntu.com/questions/759880/where-is-the-ubuntu-file-system-root-directory-in-windows-nt-subsystem-and-vice

Comment: It's not for windows 10. I don't Lxss folder in the \AppData\Local directory.

Comment: Yes it is for the Windows 10. That link even shows screen shots of Windows 10. Are you sure you are using the Linux subsystem and not Cygwin or Git Bash?

Comment: Yes, I'm using Windows Subsystem for Linux, the one that was released with Windows 10 Anniversary Update in August.

Comment: For some reason, the Lxss folder isn't visible in my \AppData\Local directory but it's there. I had to type the path to get to it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `[your-username]` with your username/user folder name.

```
C:\Users\[your-username]\AppData\Local\Lxss\
```

---

**Edit:**

Solved by `dir /AD /s` method. See comments.

Comment: I have tried this but my AppData\local directory doesn't have Lxss folder.

Comment: You can try looking for it from the root? `cd ../../*up to the root drive*` then `dir /AD /s lxss`

Comment: or look for a specific file on your /var/www/html instead of looking for the lxss directory

Comment: I had to type the path in to get to it. Thanks!